# Switch between 2 Insert Queries on Select option or Radio Button

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to run 2 different INSERT queries on the dropdown select option

If user selects **option 1** the Insert Query for Table 1 runs.
When the user selects **option 2** the other Insert query for Table 2 runs.

```
 <?php 
   if(isset($_POST['submit_form']) && isset($_POST['listings']))  {
switch ($listings) {
          case 'GradeA':
           $stmt = "INSERT INTO Packing_listA (Country, Total_bales) VALUES ('$Country' , '$Total_bales')";
        break;
          case 'GradeB':
           $sql = "INSERT INTO Packing_listB (Country, Total_bales) VALUES ('$Country' , '$Total_bales')";
        break;
       }

     if ($mysqli->query($stmt) || $mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        $last_id = $mysqli->insert_id;
        $_SESSION['ct_id'] = $last_id;
         echo "<p>New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is:  '". $last_id."'</p>"; 
         echo "<script>setTimeout('delayer()', 1000)</script>"; 
      }    
     } ?>
```

And the HTML is

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post" class="form" role="form">

    <select style="font-size:1.5em; height:45px;" class="form-control" name="listings" >
       <option>Choose Color</option>
       <option value="GradeA" <?php if($listings == "GradeA") print('selected="selected"'); ?>>GradeA</option>
       <option value="GradeB" <?php if($listings == "GradeB") print('selected="selected"'); ?>>GradeB</option>
    </select>

     <div class="form-group">
      <center>
      <button style="height:45px; font-weight:bold;" name="submit_form" class="form-control btn btn-lg btn-info">
        Next
      </button>
      </center>
     </div>

     </form>
```

But I am open to any other method Like Radio Buttons or If, Else condition or anything that works.
When the option 1 is selected only associated Query will run and vice versa.

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: this code is not working i need to select the specific query will run after selecting option from dropdown

the error is  mysqli::query(): Empty query after the switch 

if ($mysqli->query($stmt) || $mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) 

it's not executing the query i think

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll go for something like this :

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_form']) && isset($_POST['listings'])) {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO "
    ."Packing_list".($_POST['listings'] == 'GradeA'? 'A' : 'B')
    ."(Country, Total_bales)"
    ."VALUES ('$Country' , '$Total_bales')";

  if ($mysqli->query($sql)) {
    $_SESSION['ct_id'] = $mysqli->insert_id;
    echo "<p>New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is:  '".$_SESSION['ct_id'].
    "'</p>";
    echo "<script>setTimeout('delayer()', 1000)</script>";
  }
}
```

Second , I think you can make a better code (strange think in this one...)